# How can i Repeat the Alarm in android for only Monday, Tuesday and Friday

Tags: android

How can i Repeat the Alarm in Android for only Monday, Tuesday and Friday.

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), x.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, myIntent, 0);

                        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

                        //Calendar calender = new GregorianCalendar();
                        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
                        calender.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                        calender.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hours);
                        calender.set(Calendar.MINUTE, ireminder.getMin());
                        calender.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
                        calender.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
                            calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH,3);
                             calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH,2);
                              calender.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH,6);
 alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calender.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

But it is not repeating for 3 and 6 days (Monday,Tuesday and friday)
Can you guys Helpme???

Answer (score 0):

You need to set 3 separate alarms, or make your alarm receiver smart enough to schedule the next alarm when the previous fires. In your case above, looks like only the value for "6" would be used, since it is the last value set.

Comment: Is there any other way do that thing??

Comment: Actually that alarm is repeated for every week and for every month as well is it ok for that?