# Repeat scheduled tasks on selected days in Android sdk alarm manager

Tags: android, sdk, calendar, alarmmanager

I have tried to do this without bothering the experts and have read numerous threads here and on other sites. It is clearly my brain not understanding what needs to be done in order for this to work.

My goal is that the app allows the user to enter a time and one or more days in a week. All of the GUI side and storing of the dates and times I have done, however to get the alarm manager to repeat, lets say every Monday at 14:00 and then can send at 14:02 . I have used the java Calendar object to hold the times and days of the week or even used date and day of the week of the month. These are then , as needed, converted to milliseconds for it to be read in by the alarm manager.

I then have used either the alarm manager set or set repeat methods to repeat the event. All I am able to do is get it to occur once and then if I change the emulator date and time to another Monday nothing happens.

The GUI holds the hours and minutes in required variables and then these are used against the calendar objects.

The alarm manager calls a broadcast receiver for the event to occur.

Please can someone simply give an example on how to set specific days such as Monday , Wednesday Friday. I know that separate alarm managers are needed for each day and at the moment I have just focused on Monday as my main test.

Links viewed:

- [How can i Repeat the Alarm in android for only Monday, Tuesday and Friday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498453/how-can-i-repeat-the-alarm-in-android-for-only-monday-tuesday-and-friday)
- [How to repeat the alarm for "n" days at a particular time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7347120/how-to-repeat-the-alarm-for-n-days-at-a-particular-time)
- [how to repeat alarm after 1 day in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8117927/how-to-repeat-alarm-after-1-day-in-android)

---

Managed to figure this out now and so follows my answer:

The following code calculates the remaining days between now and the day needed for the scheduled task. the variable whichday is passed via parameter from the method this code belongs to. In the understanding of this whichday represents days of the week 1 through to 7 where 1 is Sunday , 2 is Monday and so .

```
//This gets the current day of the week as of TODAY / NOW
int checkcurrentday = getcurtime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);

// This calculates the days between now and the day needed which is represented by whichday.
int numberofdays = Calendar.SATURDAY + whichday - checkcurrentday;

//Now add NOT set the difference of the days to your Calendar object
tMondayOn.add(Calendar.DATE, numberofdays);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, you need to first use the Java Calendar API (or Joda!) to figure out when the next monday is. Set the alarm to to that time in milliseconds then use setRepeating and pass in a long that represents the interval of one week.

Comment: LuxuryMode -Thanks for your reply, you know after posting this question my brain started to wonder about the parameters in the Alarm Manager and how the interval part worked. I then wondered if there was a once a week interval option via the Alarm Manager. I think I have , as usual, been making this harder that it actually is :) I will try your suggestion. Thanks for your time on this. Should I use the day interval from Alarm Manager and then * by 7 to move forward a week?

Comment: Right that appeared to work when I do AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY*7 but when I move into a new month and pick Monday but make sure that the time is not set to when the event will occur, I notice that the two broadcast receivers are fired off straight away , then if I set the time to when it starts the first - it works and does so when it fires the second- any reason why it starts both broadcast receivers like this?

Comment: @TimCS, do yourself a favor and log a formatted date whenever you are using it for an alarm manager. I've dealt extensively with alarms and learned that you really need to first confirm that you're getting the date that you think you are. The most common reason for alarms going off right away is that the date object actually represents a time that is already passed in which case it goes off immediately.

Comment: LuxuryMode, I assume you mean for me to show the date and time on screen so that I know it is correct? Also the event does not trigger before the specified time when it is first set only when I move forward into a new month. However I will do as you suggest and show the date and time on screen if that is what I understand you mean. I am using the calendar DAY_OF_THE_WEEK_OF_THE_MONTH (I have had to guess the name here as I do not have it in front of me ) and set this to 2 for Monday would that appear to be correct?

Comment: LuxuryMode - I decided to output the time and date from the two calendar objects to screen. I had set the emulator back to the 14th before setting the day I wanted to re-occur the event on and then set the times on and off. It does show that the day is the 14th of November (Monday) and then shows the times correctly. Is it because it is holding the 14th that it re-triggers the events straight away when I move forward to the next Monday? if so why then does it correctly trigger the events on the next Monday at the specified times? the interval perhaps?

Comment: I think I may have got this working but I need to confirm my findings for certain. LuxuryMode thanks again for your input. I am guessing that I have tried that many permutations that I got lost where I was. Also I noticed that for some reason I had created the calendar object in the onCreate method and then again when called at the point of defining the times and dates. I have removed the second reference so whether that has made any difference I do not know.

Comment: TimCS, glad to hear you think you may have gotten it working. If I have some time, I'll post up a little sample of how I like to set alarms and how to actually test that you set them to what you think you did..

Comment: LuxuryMode sorry for that not done that many posts and forget such matters. I am still having an issue with this regarding make it repeat on a specific day - I will post the code , if it will allow me to, into the main post at the start